# WP-CLI on existing installtions?

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

When I try to get the version number of an existing installation that wasn't created by WP CLI I get an error:

```
wp core version --path='/Users/plee/clients/burger_king/wp'
```

The error message is

```
WP-CLI needs WordPress 3.7 or later to work properly. The version currently installed is .
```

You see that somehow it recognizes a WordPress installation but it can't read the version number. It is a working installation with the newest core update.

Is there any way to make this visible to WP CLI?

Comment: Normally this should work just fine...

Comment: Do other cli commands, like 'wp --info,' work? If you get the version error for everything, I had a similar problem and solved it with this:

    scl enable ea-php70  'wp --info'

This will force cli to use php 7.0. You'll have to prefix all your commands this way.